# How to generate auto id in c++?

Tags: c++, class, oop

I have a class,in which I want the id ,to be generated automaticly;

```
    class Id{
    private:
    int id;
    Automat automat;
    }
```

And the class:

```
     class Array
    {
      Id* arr;//Every object to have a unique integer id;
      int number_of_elements;
      int capacity;
    }
```

Comment: Use a constructor to initialize it to a suitable unique value?

Comment: Use Uniform int distribution in a loop where you compare the generated value with your existing values, if it is unique insert it.

Comment: "_Every object to have a unique integer id_" - Wouldn't `reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(this);` work in that case?

Comment: @TedLyngmo only if you never copy or move those objects

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking of not having a static id, but inheriting from something like `struct Id { std::uintptr_t get_id() const { return reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(this); } };`.

Answer (score 4):

You must use of a `static` member to counting the objects :

```
class Id
{
    public:
        Id()
        {
            id = unique_id++;
        }

    int get_id()
    {
        return id;
    }

    private:
        int id;
        static int unique_id;
}
```

Initialize static member in the source file :

```
static int Id::unique_id = 0;
```

Create objects :

```
Id id1;        // id1.get_id() will return 1
Id id2;        // id2.get_id() will return 2
Id id3;        // id3.get_id() will return 3
```

***Notice :*** *This is a simple example but you can improve it and add conditions to better handling.*

Answer (score 1):

You should add a constructor which calls `<random>`. Then the Array class should check for matching ids and replace them with new objects.