# How to generate an automatic and sequential class ID?

Tags: c++, class

I would like to generate an automatic ID attached to every instantiation of a class, respecting the order of appearance of the instantiation statements in the source code. I found this: [How to generate auto id in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56128482/how-to-generate-auto-id-in-c)

At the end of that example it looks like the ID produced by incrementing a static variable is unique and also sequential:

```
Id id1;        // id1.get_id() will return 1
Id id2;        // id2.get_id() will return 2
Id id3;        // id3.get_id() will return 3
```

I can understand the IDs are unique, but can I be sure they are also sequential?
Couldn't be, for instance, I get something like:

```
Id id1;        // id1.get_id() will return 2
Id id2;        // id2.get_id() will return 1
Id id3;        // id3.get_id() will return 3
```

...because who knows in which order the compiler is going to do the instantiations?

Is that ok, or is there a safe way to get the desired result?

Best regards

Comment: Only you can conclude whether "is that ok", or not, based on whatever you need to accomplish with those ids; noone else can make that decision for you.

Comment: The order of initialization in any one cpp file is well defined, but if you have two different cpp files there is no synchronization between those and so you can't know the ordering between files.

Comment: For single-thread applications, the sequence is guaranteed to be incremental, I don't know why you thought it would not, unless your compiler decided to go haywire.

Comment: @Sam, maybe I was not clear enough, I mean: how can I create a unique and also sequential ID? Is the presented method really doing this or is there any pitfall in it? Is it really going to do what it looks like, or not?

Comment: I feel like we're having an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Please clarify why do you need it to be that way.

Comment: @thedemons, somewhere I read the compiler can do optimisations and may decide to change the order of instantiation to better allocate the memory. Maybe I am wrong.

Comment: @zorzin It can only do so if it does not change the observable behavior of the program.  If your program relies on the initialization order like yours does and a change would make a difference then it cannot break that.

Comment: It sure can: static initialization order fiasco can trigger this.

Answer (score 0):

> can I be sure they are also sequential?

Yes. The initialisation of `id1` is [*sequenced before*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order) the initialisation of `id2`, similarly `id2` and `id3`.

Comment: as far as I understand, if the instantiation was done in single row like: Id id1, id2, id3; then the sequencing would not have been guaranteed, and the trick might not work. Am I correct?

Comment: @zorzin no, those are [treated the same](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.decl#3)

Answer (score 0):

It is a safe way to get the desired results as long as you're not working with threads.

A single-threaded program will always execute in the order you code.
If you declare:

```
MyClass A, B, C;
```

You will always get A=0 B=1 C=2.

Whereas if you declared:

```
MyClass A, C, B;
```

You will get A=0, B=2, C=1.

If you don't know the concept of threads, you are most likely working on a single-threaded program. So rest assured it is safe!

Comment: If the questioner did need to have the counter work reliably in a multithreaded context, he could set the counter's type to `std::atomic<int>` instead of `int` to achieve that.